Drift occurs when the robot did pure rotation during SLAM(slam toolbox)
I tried to do SLAM using slam toolbox on ROS 2 Jazzy with Gazebo Harmonic.
But, Drift occurs when the robot did pure rotation during SLAM(slam toolbox).

Steps to reproduce
mkdir -p ~/dev_ws/src
cd ~/dev_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2.git -b prepare-jazzy
cd ..
rosdep install -y -i --from-paths src/megarover_samples_ros2
colcon build --symlink-install
source ~/dev_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_with_sample_world.launch.py
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_mapping.launch.py
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard

type l key

Remarks
On the other hands, there is no problem in ROS 2 Humble with Gazebo Classic.
mkdir -p ~/dev_ws/src
cd ~/dev_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/atinfinity/megarover_samples_ros2.git -b humble
cd ..
rosdep install -y -i --from-paths src/megarover_samples_ros2
colcon build --symlink-install
source ~/dev_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_with_sample_world.launch.py
ros2 launch megarover_samples_ros2 vmegarover_mapping.launch.py
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard

type l key


There's 2 possible things going on here:
1.
Your robot's odometry or TF transformations are incorrect and are creating bad motion or transforms that the SLAM system cannot compensate for.
If you move the robot around in the odometry frame, do things look good, don't drift at all, etc? If yes, then see (2). If no, address that.




Most SLAM systems need "real" environments to work well. The exact straight line of a wall in a 'simple' scene without any unique features / objects typically don't work well. You might think a simple space should be "easy" but its actually much harder. If you add some more objects or try it out on a real space, you shouldn't see this issue.

If you move the robot around in the odometry frame, do things look good, don't drift at all, etc?
No.

I launch ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py with my world(vmegarover_sample.sdf). And, I launch mapping(slam_toolbox). As a result, there is no problem. So, I suspect this issue is caused by either Gazebo(Physics) or model(SDF).
